# Number of incongruent integers that have a given order modulo p.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So, I'm studying number theory by myself on a book I found on the internet, I'll leave a link to the pdf, the page i'm refering to is page 96, there is this one lemma stated and proved in the book that I seem to not get at all: 
"We now prove a lemma that gives us how many incongruent integers can have
a given order modulo p, lemma: let p be a prime and m a positive integer such that p-1=m*k for some integer k, then:

S(m)= |{m: 0 < m < p, m ∈ Z}| ≤ φ(m)"

I've studied the order of an integer mod m, but i'm not completely sure what he means by "integer with a given order modulo p", does it count how many a's are there such that a^(ordᵖa)≡1 (mod p)? 
also, that statement about S(m), could someone try to explain it to me a bit more clearly? i'm really confused...

link of the book's pdf: https://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/An-Introductory-in-Elementary-Number-Theory.pdf

P.S. I'm in 4th year of highschool I'm studying this stuff because I truly love it, so I might not be familiar with some more advanced stuff, but if I have to be honest this is the first theorem of the book that i find kinda strange...

Comment: For a fixed $m$, one looks at the set $\{ a : \operatorname{ord}_p a = m\}$, presumably considering only integers $0 < a < p$. That's those $a$ which have order $m$ (exactly, not just $a^m = 1$, which means the order of $a$ divides $m$). The statement of Lemma 11 is badly mangled, it looks like the author decided to change notation and messed that up. The intended statement is (equivalent to) "… Then $S(m) = \lvert\{ a : 0 < a < p, \operatorname{ord}_p a = m\}\rvert \leqslant \phi(m)$." Does that make more sense to you?

Comment: We always have $a^{ord (a)}\equiv 1 \mod p$ because $ord(a)$ is defined as the least $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $a^n\equiv 1 \mod p.$

Comment: It helps to know a result of Fermat:  For some $r$ we have $ord(r)=p-1.$ So when $1\leq j<p$ there is a unique $n_j$ with $1\leq n_j\leq p-1$ such that $j\equiv r^{n_j} \mod p$.... And the result    that if $p\not | \;a$ then $ord(a)|(p-1).$....

Comment: @DanielFischer Really appreciate your answer, now i finally understand the lemma, cannot thank you enough!